# What's needed to get Views data export working with a Block view?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I have been successfully using the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to export data to CSV.

However, when attempting to do the same from a block view, the path (required by VDE) for the CSV returns a 404 error.The block does not have a specific path because it is rendered in node pages.

How can I get VDE to work with a block view?

Comment: I'm one of the module maintainers. I did a quick test. I cannot reproduce the issue with a view and a single block display to which I add a data export. I assign a path to the data export display and attach it to the block display. It seems to work fine.